# Javascript Filter trying to avoid multiple if statements

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I have to filter an array based on some conditions. I want to avoid having to write out a bunch if statements. My code below shows pretty much what I want to accomplish. The * you see is just me trying to say filter to any (like a wild card). Do you have any idea how I can best accomplish my goal? Thank you

```
let x =eq.filter(eq => eq.empid == selectedTech === 'ALL Techs'? '*' : selectedTech 
    &&  eq.code == selectedStatus === 'ALL Statuses'? '*' : selectedStatus 
    &&  eq.cellnum == phn === '' ? '*': phn
    &&  eq.jobid == jobid === '' ? '*': jobid
    );
```

Example of the object:

```
var eq = [{
  empid: 1,
  jobid: 27,
  code: "Not Started",
  cellnum: "3058888888",
  brand: "GK",
  model: "X500"
}, {
  empid: 1,
  jobid: 33,
  code: "Not Started",
  cellnum: "3058888899",
  brand: "Mackie",
  model: "X500"
}, {
  empid: 2,
  jobid: 35,
  code: "In Progress",
  cellnum: "3058888877",
  brand: "Samson",
  model: "X522"
}, {
  empid: 1,
  jobid: 36,
  code: "Not Started",
  cellnum: "3058888866",
  brand: "Mackie",
  model: "X467"
}, {
  empid: 1,
  jobid: 37,
  code: "In Progress",
  cellnum: "3058888800",
  brand: "Fender",
  model: "X500"
}]
}
```

Comment: Whitespace is your friend, if nothing else.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `eq.jobid == jobid === '' ? '*': jobid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `'*'`, use `eq.whatever` there since it will be guaranteed to compare equal to itself.

And use parentheses to ensure that the precedence is what you want. I'm not sure offhand how the `==` precedence compares to the tertiary.

```js
let x = eq.filter(eq => eq.empid == (selectedTech === 'ALL Techs' ? eq.empid : selectedTech) &&
  eq.code == (selectedStatus === 'ALL Statuses' ? eq.code : selectedStatus) &&
  eq.cellnum == (phn === '' ? eq.cellnum : phn) &&
  eq.jobid == (jobid === '' ? eq.jobid : jobid)
);
```

Maybe a clearer way to do it is either compare the filter variable to its wildcard value or the object property.

```js
var eq = [{
  empid: 1,
  jobid: 27,
  code: "Not Started",
  cellnum: "3058888888",
  brand: "GK",
  model: "X500"
}, {
  empid: 1,
  jobid: 33,
  code: "Not Started",
  cellnum: "3058888899",
  brand: "Mackie",
  model: "X500"
}, {
  empid: 2,
  jobid: 35,
  code: "In Progress",
  cellnum: "3058888877",
  brand: "Samson",
  model: "X522"
}, {
  empid: 1,
  jobid: 36,
  code: "Not Started",
  cellnum: "3058888866",
  brand: "Mackie",
  model: "X467"
}, {
  empid: 1,
  jobid: 37,
  code: "In Progress",
  cellnum: "3058888800",
  brand: "Fender",
  model: "X500"
}];

let selectedTech = 'ALL Techs',
  selectedStatus = 'In Progress',
  phn = '3058888800',
  jobid = 37;

let x = eq.filter(eq =>
  (selectedTech === 'ALL Techs' || eq.empid == selectedTech) &&
  (selectedStatus === 'ALL Statuses' || eq.code == selectedStatus) &&
  (phn === '' || eq.cellnum == phn) &&
  (jobid === '' || eq.jobid == jobid)
);

console.log(x);

phn = "123456789";

x = eq.filter(eq =>
  (selectedTech === 'ALL Techs' || eq.empid == selectedTech) &&
  (selectedStatus === 'ALL Statuses' || eq.code == selectedStatus) &&
  (phn === '' || eq.cellnum == phn) &&
  (jobid === '' || eq.jobid == jobid)
);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: @jarmod No, `==` is correct. We're comparing a property in `eq` to either a filter variable or itself.

Comment: @jarmod Take a look at the update, it may make it clearer.

Comment: Yup, OK, makes sense. Strange that OP would use `==` in one situation but `===` in another.

Comment: Hi. None of the solutions above seem to work. It just returns back all the data and no filters are applied. I dont really use == over === for any particular reason, I could make them the same. Mayb I can try REGEX as an option for this? Not sure what other route to take other then multiple if conditions which I really would like to avoid...

Comment: Can you update the question with some actual data and the expected result?

Comment: Im not currently able to edit my question. I cant seem to find how to update my question. Basically the selectedTech, selectedStatus, phn and jobid are user selections from dropdowns on input fields, they press a search button and I have to filter the array eq so it matches their selections.  phn nd jobid may be blank, and the other 2 may have Selected All  whcih is why I was using "wild cards".

Comment: as an example of the array of objects : var  eq = [{empid:1,jobid:27,code:"Not Started",cellnum: "3058888888",brand:"GK", model: "X500"},
        {empid:1,jobid:33,code:"Not Started",cellnum: "3058888899",brand:"Mackie", model: "X500"},
        {empid:2,jobid:35,code:"In Progress",cellnum: "3058888877",brand:"Samson", model: "X522"},
        {empid:1,jobid:36,code:"Not Started",cellnum: "3058888866",brand:"Mackie", model: "X467"},
        {empid:1,jobid:37,code:"In Progress",cellnum: "3058888800",brand:"Fender", model: "X500"}    ]}

Comment: I don't know why you can't edit the question. Just click the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66447869/edit) link below it.

Comment: I updated the answer with the sample data, and showed that it works. Are you sure that the wildcard values for `selectedTech` and `selectedStatus` are exactly what's in the form?

Comment: thank you @Barmar your solution works great! the only issue is if there is not data that matches the filters, I get back the entire array. Maybe I can figure that part out or maybe you have a simple option. Thank you so much

Comment: No it doesn't. I added a second example with `phn` that doesn't match, and it returns an empty array.